# Vagrantpress + composer

Tags: php, json, linux

I was looking at the [roots.io](http://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/) blog, where I learned about Vagrant and Composer which in combination seem to give you a more intelligent development environment and dependency management system. I choose to get and install [Vagrantpress](http://vagrantpress.org) since it seems like the easiest way to get started with wordpress + vagrant. The plus of Vagrantpress is that it installs Wordpress and all its dependencies for you. As I understand Composer in adjunction with Wordpress, is that the easiest way to combine the two is to use the [Outlandishs](http://outlandish.com) [WordPress Packagist](http://wpackagist.org). Now my question is, how are people using Composer and Vagrantpress tougher? How does your setup look like? Are there any good examples of composer.json file + Vagrantfile for Vagrantpress?

/PS: If someone with enough rep could create the Vagrant and composer tags that would be great. No relevant tags really exist, but I hope the question is relevant enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use Vagrantpress and Composer directly together easily. Half of Vagrantpress is the WordPress setup itself which isn't compatible. If you still wanted to leverage the base work Vagrantpress has done with PHP, Apache, MySQL etc, you could fork it and modify their WP module found here: https://github.com/chad-thompson/vagrantpress/blob/master/puppet/modules/wordpress/manifests/init.pp

It would still require a decent amount of changes though since you'd need to install Composer, modify their wp-config.php (the ones outlined in the Roots blog post), and run `composer install` instead of downloading the WP tar.gz.

It might just be easier to built a custom LAMP style Vagrant file with https://puphpet.com/ and then write your own manifests for the WP/Composer part.

Comment: As always, your the man!